# How to create a scatter plot where x-axis represents a day by hours with datetime object? chartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am creating a scatter plot with chartJS and react-chartjs-2. I am getting data for x-axis in the format of :

```
2020-07-06T09:17:15.424+00:00
```

for the y-axis I will get data in the format of:

```
HH:mm
```

I would like to have an x-axis which would represent a whole day by an hour, so it start at 00:00 and ends at 23:59 or 24:00. The question I have how do I put the labels into chartJS so that if I pass a datetime object or a string the scatter plot automatically detects it's value and puts it exactly where it belongs and not on the line of the label.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

When using [scatter charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html), you don't define `labels` but define the data as an array of objects containing `x` and `y` properties each.

Further you need to define the `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

> Please note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) for the functionality of the time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet.

```js
var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [
        { x: "05:22", y: 12 },
        { x: "12:13", y: 19 },
        { x: "13:45", y: 3 },
        { x: "18:31", y: 5 },
        { x: "19:05", y: 2 },
        { x: "22:55", y: 3 }
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      pointRadius: 8,
      pointHoverRadius: 8
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    scales: {      
      xAxes: [{     
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'HH:mm',
          unit: 'hour',
          stepSize: 1,
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'HH:mm'   
          },          
          tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm'          
        },
        ticks: {
          min: '00:00',
          max: '24:00',
          callback: (value, index) => index == 24 ? '24:00' : value
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 5
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am actually using react-chartjs-2, but I would assume building graphs there is really similar. I am using momentjs as well as a separate library. Could I update my post with the code I have and you could see why it is not working correctly for me. I am a bit lost with this problem. The question I basically have is do I need to pass a moment object to the x coordinate or can I simply pass a string and then use the options you've defined here? Because I tried passing moment object and it formats the x-axis in milliseconds rather than dates.

Comment: Plesase post a new question for this separate issue. It will make it eadier to provide accurate answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874284/how-to-build-a-time-x-axis-where-it-starts-on-monday-and-ends-on-sunday-for-scat Did that.

Comment: Hmm, I tried copying your solution and it doesn't seem to work. I am passing time in the format "HH:mm" as a string to x and using the same xAxes options as you are.

Comment: My bad... I am using react-chartjs-2 and I had to pass options as a separate variable from the data. Works now.